# cant a CSRF token be stolen using iframe?

Tags: csrf, iframe

from what I understand a common approach to storing a CSRF token would be:

1. the client retrieves from the server a CSRF token
2. the token is stored in an input element inside the form like this:

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="abc123supersecrettoken"> 
</form>
```

my question is, would an attack like this be possible, and if so, how can a site be protected:

1. user logins into facebook.com
2. user goes to evil.com, the site has he following iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/changeUserPasswordForm"></iframe>
```

3. with some basic DOM manipulation on the iframe, the CSRF token could be accessed by the attacker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would an attack like this be possible

This would not be possible. The [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents cross-origin reading. This applies also to an iframe from a different domain which is embedded in the current page.